# When to use awoke/awakened/awoken?

Tags: verbs, usage, conjugations

I am confused by what seems to me to be the more frequent use of the word *awoken*. During my reading, I have usually come across "He awoke" or "He was awakened". Now I am reading "He was awoken" and "He waked". (I would say "He was awakened" or "He woke/awoke to the sound of....") Would somebody please help me in my total confusion? Is there a verb here that I just can't conjugate? Has *awoken* become more common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Awake and awaken are two distinct verbs that both mean "to rise from sleep." The verb forms for awake are irregular, but the most common choices are awake, awoke, and was awoken. The verb forms for awaken are regular: awakens, awakened, was awakened.

For more info look [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-awaken-awoken-awakened).

Comment: Thank you for the link. That helped me. I am a little amused that they define it as "to rise from sleep". It doesn't sound like it means to become conscious after sleeping. Maybe I'd better look up "rise"! Your help is much appreciated.